# How to parameterize the elliptic equation with length of arc $t$

Tags: parametric, parametrization

As we know, the equation of elliptic is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=r^2$$
But I want to use its parametric form,the $t$ is representative of the arc length.So how to parameterize the elliptic equation?

Comment: The usual analog for the $(r\cos t, r\sin(t)$ parameterizatoin of a circle is $(ar\cos t, br\sin(t)$ where $t$ again runs from $0$ to $2\pi$. But this is a parameterization in terms of angle from the origin, not arc length. I would not be shocked to learn that an ellipse can be parameterized in terms of its arc length using Jacobi elliptic functions sn and cn, with $k$ for those functions depending on the eccentricity of the ellipse. I would be shocked to learn that there is any more elementary parameterization in terms of arc length.

Comment: @MarkFischler I want to partition a elliptic into some isometric arc length.For the sake of it,I want to use a parameter of arc  length to parameterize the elliptic equation. :)

Comment: Is there a way to prove that a function does not have an anti derivative or is it simply that no one has found one yet. For example
 $$ \int_{}^{} \sqrt{1 +a\cdot cos^{2}(x) }\hspace{3mm} dx $$

Is there a way to prove that this integral cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of elementary functions?

Comment: See a newer post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284133/parameterization-of-an-ellipse-by-arc-length).

Answer (score 3):

As Mark Fischler commented, I do not see how this could be done.

Using $x=a\, r\cos(t)$, $y=a \,r\sin(t)$, the arc length is given by $$L=r\int_{0}^{u} \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2(t)+b^2 \sin^2(t)}\,dt=br\, E\left(u\left|1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right. \right)$$ You cannot extract explicitely $u$ from this equation except writing
$$u=\text{InverseFunction}[\text{EllipticE},1,2]\left[\frac{L}{b
   r},1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right]$$ which is not the most convenient.

However, for cases, what you could do is to use parametric splines $x=f(L)$ and $y=g(L)$

**Edit** *(six years later)*

If you are optimistic and want to solve for $u$ the equation
$$L=b\,r\, E\left(u\left|1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right. \right)$$  let
$$A=\frac L{b\,r} \qquad \text{and}\qquad k=1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$ and use the series expansion
$$E(u|k)=u-\frac{k}{6}u^3+\frac{(4-3 k) k }{120} u^5+O\left(u^7\right)$$ and power series reversion would give
$$u=A+\frac{ k}{6}A^3+\frac{k (13
   k-4)}{120} A^5 +O\left(A^7\right)$$

Comment: @ mayi Attempting this   parametrically as $ ( x(s),y(s))= \int ( \cos \phi(s), \sin \phi (s)) \,ds$ bbgodfrey's answer to my question.[ArcSoln][1]

  [1]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147688/how-can-i-convert-a-numerical-solution-to-an-analytical-one

Comment: @Narasimham. Thanks for the link ! It is very interesting.

Comment: Glad you liked it, am still looking at further generalization including rotations in the plane..